# Create a schedule in Django

Tags: django, database

I’m working on Django project “management system for clinic” and I have no idea how to create a schedule for doctors.

For example administrator makes an appointment for patient. I want him to see a schedule of doctor and which time is placed or free.

As I understand I should create model “Time” and connect it with a doctor, but I don’t really know what should I do after this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Create a function for the scheduling in your views.py file